# How to setup dotnetcore target for build and tests

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, .net-core

I'm trying to build and test [aspnet/identity](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity). I'm having dotnet core 2.1, but the sources are configured to "package with 2.2-preview".

There are many "references" to the dotnet version:

for each project:

- dependencies/.NETCoreApp 2.2
- project properties/package version/2.2.0-preview1-t000
- project properties/build/conditional compilation symbols /NETCOREAPP;NETCOREAPP2_2

in a directory containing many projects:

- Directory.Build.props/the following value:

  ```
  DeveloperBuildTestTfms=netcoreapp2.2
  ```

How and where can I configure one or a set of projects (and test projects) to work with dotnet core 2.1 instead of 2.2-preview ? Can I do that once (instead of once per project) ?